# How to inflate a context menu when an Item in ListItem is on hold?

Tags: android, contextmenu, listitem

I have a ListView on my Android project, and when the item clicked, it will go to the "selected item detail info" activity. And when one of the item on hold, i want it to inflate or to pop up a context menu, it just like the one in some music player list.
I have no idea which event method that I should override to catch the onHold event of that listItem. Please somebody show me the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should set on your `ListView` an [`OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html).

If you are using `ActionBar` it would also be nice to set the `ActionBar` in [`ActionMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) when an item is selected. For a quick tutorial for `ActionMode` you can check [Vogella's List Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: Oh, I got the point mate! thanks for the help. I've tried it and got succeed